# What is the approximate formula for the divisor function?

Tags: number-theory

Divisor function as in the function that counts the number of positive integers dividing the input n.

I would think that it would be $ln(n)+\gamma$ since $$\sum_{f=1}^n \frac{1}{f} \approx ln(n) + \gamma$$
The logic is that any number $f$ has a $\frac{1}{f}$ chance of dividing a random $n>f$, but I can't find anything online that says this, only approximate growth rates of the divisor function among other things.

Comment: this is not clear.  Which "divisor function" are you thinking of?  Why would some other limit have to be the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: should be more clear now

Comment: So, if $d(n)$ is the number of positive factors of $n$, you think $d(n)$ should approach $\ln (n)$?  If $n=p$ is prime, then $d(p)=2$ so, maybe you mean $\limsup$ or something like that?

Comment: How can this be "approximate"?  There are infinitely many n (namely the primes) for which the number of divisors is 2.  For the partial sums of this sequence, we have $n \log(n) + (2 \gamma - 1) n - 4 \sqrt{n} - 1 \le a(n) \le n \log(n) + (2 \gamma - 1) n + 4 \sqrt{n}$ (see [OEIS sequence A006218](https://oeis.org/A006218))

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574080/specifying-a-least-upper-bound-for-the-number-of-divisors-as-a-function-of-n) for an upper bound on $d(n)$.

Comment: ok as n goes to infinity, what function f yields the lowest sum of $|f(x)-d(x)| $ for all positive x less than n?

Comment: That's not the question you mean.  $f(x)=d(x)$ clearly gives the minimum for that sum.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37774/asymptotic-formula-for-dn-n-summation) is a question which addresses the asymptotics of $\sum \frac {d(n)}n$.  And [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_order_of_an_arithmetic_function) is a discussion of "average order" which is possibly what you intend.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4425078/asymptotic-on-max-dn-1-leq-n-leq-n/4425697#4425697) as well.